# Kuratowski closure-complement question involving unions and intersections

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space containing subsets $A$ and $B$ such that

$$\tag1ikA=ikiA=iA\subsetneq A=kA=kikA=kiA$$
$$\tag2kiB=ikiB=iB\subsetneq B\subsetneq kB=kikB=ikB$$

where $k$ is closure and $i$ is interior. These relations, as well as those implied for the complements $cA$ and $cB$, are represented by the following Hasse diagrams where sets in a given diagram are equal iff they have the same color:

[image: Hasse diagrams Kuratowski closure complement 14 sets]

Suppose $A\cup B$ satisfies $(1)$ and $A\cap B$ satisfies $(2){:}$

[image: Hasse diagrams Kuratowski unions intersections]

Finally, suppose $A\cup cB$ is clopen (this might already be implied).

Does it follow that $kiA\setminus ikiA=ki(A\cap cB)\setminus iki(A\cap cB)?$

Comment: Why did you also assume (1) and (2) for the complements?

Comment: @Berci the relations satisfied by $cA$ (which are similar to $(1)$, but slightly different) and $cB$ ($(2)$) follow from the conditions put on $A$ and $B$.  All four sets are relevant to the problem, so all four diagrams seemed worth displaying.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the diagrams. Why would the same hold for the complement?

Comment: The conditions on $B$ are inconsistent.

Comment: @Berci the diagrams (for $A$ and $cA$) are different because their colorings are different.  The Hasse diagram for $cS$ $(\text{any }S\subset X)$ is obtained by flipping the diagram for $S$ upside down and interchanging $ki$ and $ik,$ because $i(cS)=(ckc)cS=c(kS),$ $iki(cS)=(ckc)k(ckc)cS=c(kikS),$ $ik(cS)=(ckc)kcS=c(kiS),$ $ki(cS)=cck(ckc)cS=c(ikS),$ $kik(cS)=cck(ckc)kcS=c(ikiS),$ and $k(cS)=cckcS=c(iS).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you'll need to provide more detail than that. I currently see no reason to edit the question.

Comment: I apologize. I was very tired when I wrote that. It $is$ consistent. For example if $X=\Bbb R$ and $B=\Bbb Q.$

Comment: The motivation for this question is explained here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the diagrams alone imply the equation. They also imply $A\cup cB$ is clopen.

**Proof.** Let $\textsf{id}$ denote the identity operator. For each $\{\sigma,\tau\}\subset\{\textsf{id},i,ki,iki,k,ik,kik\},$ sets $E$ satisfying $\sigma E=\tau E$ are characterized in [*A Further Note on Closure and Interior Operators*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311193) (written by Thomas A. Chapman when he was an undergrad). Two theorems from this paper will be useful here.  We cite and prove both.

**Theorem 2.** A subset $E$ of a topological space $X$ satisfies $kiE=kE$ iff $E=iE\cup F$ where $F$ has a void interior in the subspace $E$ of $X.$

*Proof:* $(\Rightarrow)$ Define $F=E\setminus iE.$ Let $o_E$ denote the operator $o$ in the subspace $E$ of $X.$  Note that $$\eqalign{k_E(iE)&=&\bigcap\{D\cap E:kD=D\supset iE\}\cr&=&E\cap\bigcap\{D:kD=D\supset iE\}\cr&=&E\cap kiE=E\cap kE=E.\cr}$$ Thus $$\eqalign{i_EF&=&c_Ek_Ec_E(E\setminus iE)\cr&=&c_Ek_E(iE)=c_EE=\varnothing.}$$ Clearly, $E=iE\cup F.$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $q\in kE$ and $U$ be any open neighborhood of $q.$ Every neighborhood of $q$ intersects $E,$ hence $U\cap E\neq\varnothing.$ Since $U\cap E$ is open in $E$ and $i_EF=\varnothing,$ we have $(U\cap E)\cap F=\varnothing.$ Since $E=iE\cup F,$ it follows that $U\cap iE\neq\varnothing.$ Since $U$ is arbitrary, this implies $q\in kiE.$ Thus $kE\subset kiE.$ Since the opposite inclusion always holds, conclude $kiE=kE.$

**Theorem 5.** A subset $E$ of a topological space $X$ satisfies $kiE=iE$ iff $E=iE\cup F$ where $iE$ is clopen and $iE\cap F=\varnothing=iF.$

*Proof:* $(\Rightarrow)$ The hypothesis $kiE=iE$ implies that $iE$ is clopen. 
 Define $F=E\setminus iE.$ Since $iE\cup iF$ is an open set contained in $A,$ we have $iE\cup iF=iE.$ Since $iE\cap iF=\varnothing,$ this implies $iF=\varnothing.$ Clearly, $iE\cap F=\varnothing.$

$(\Leftarrow)$ The equation $kiE=iE$ holds since $iE$ is clopen.

By Theorem 2 and the diagrams, it follows that
$$\tag1A=iA\cup V$$ where $A$ is closed, $iA\neq\varnothing,$ $V\neq\varnothing,$ and $iA\cap V=\varnothing=i_AV.$

Similarly,
$$\tag2A\cup B=i(A\cup B)\cup W$$ where $A\cup B$ is closed, $i(A\cup B)\neq\varnothing,$ $W\neq\varnothing,$ and $i(A\cup B)\cap W=\varnothing=i_{A\cup B}W.$

By Theorem 5 and the diagrams, it follows that
$$\tag3B=iB\cup Y$$ where $iB$ is clopen (possibly empty), $Y\neq\varnothing,$ and $iB\cap Y=\varnothing=iY.$

Similarly,
$$\tag4cB=icB\cup Z$$ where $icB$ is clopen (possibly empty), $Z\neq\varnothing,$ and $icB\cap Z=\varnothing=iZ.$

**Claim 1.** $i(A\cup B)=iA\cup iB$ and $i(A\cup cB)=iA\cup icB.$

*Proof.* Since $A$ is closed, we have $$\eqalign{i(A\cup B)\setminus A&=&i(A\cup B)\cap cA\cr&=&i(A\cup B)\cap icA\cr&=&i[(A\cup B)\cap cA]\cr&=&i(B\cap cA)\cr&=&iB\cap icA\cr&=&iB\cap cA\cr&=&iB\setminus A.}$$ It follows that $i(A\cup B)\subset A\cup iB.$ Since $iB$ is clopen, $i(A\cup B)\setminus iB$ is an open set contained in $A.$ Hence $i(A\cup B)\setminus iB\subset iA.$ Thus $i(A\cup B)\subset iA\cup iB.$ The opposite inclusion always holds, so $i(A\cup B)=iA\cup iB.$ The second equation holds by the same argument with $B$ replaced by $cB.$

**Claim 2.** $Y\cup Z$ is a clopen subset of $iA.$

*Proof.* Suppose $Y\cap cA\neq\varnothing.$ Since $Y\subset ciB$ and $ciB$ is clopen, this implies that $cA\cap ciB$ is a nonempty open set. Thus, since $i_{A\cup B}W=\varnothing,$ the set $(cA\cap ciB)\cap(A\cup B)$ must intersect $i(A\cup B)=iA\cup iB.$ But this is impossible, since $(cA\cap ciB)\cap (iA\cup iB)=\varnothing.$ This contradiction implies $Y\subset A.$

Replacing $B$ with $cB$ and $Y$ with $Z$ in the above argument yields $Z\subset A.$ Hence, $Y\cup Z\subset A.$

Note that $X=B\cup cB=(iB\cup Y)\cup(icB\cup Z).$ Thus, $kB=cicB=iB\cup(Y\cup Z)$ and $kcB=ciB=icB\cup(Y\cup Z).$ Hence, $kB\cap kcB=Y\cup Z.$ Since $kB$ and $kcB$ are each clopen, this implies that $Y\cup Z$ is a clopen subset of $A,$ which further implies that $Y\cup Z\subset iA.$

**Aside.** Since $\varnothing\subsetneq Y\cup Z\subset iA\subsetneq X,$ Claim 2 implies $X$ is not connected.

**Corollary 1.** $iA\cap kB$ is clopen.

*Proof.* Claim 2 and the diagrams imply that $iA\cap kB$ is a union of two clopen sets: $$\eqalign{iA\cap kB&=&iA\cap[iB\cup(Y\cup Z)]\cr&=&(iA\cap iB)\cup[iA\cap(Y\cup Z)]\cr&=&i(A\cap B)\cup(Y\cup Z).}$$

**Claim 3.** $k(iA\setminus kB)=(iA\setminus kB)\cup V$ and $ik(iA\setminus kB)\cap V=\varnothing.$

*Proof.* By $(1),$ Corollary 1 and the diagrams, we have $$\eqalign{(iA\cap kB)\cup (iA\setminus kB)\cup V&=&A\cr&=&kiA\cr&=&k[(iA\cap kB)\cup(iA\setminus kB)]\cr&=&k(iA\cap kB)\cup k(iA\setminus kB)\cr&=&(iA\cap kB)\cup k(iA\setminus kB).}$$ Since $c(iA\cap kB)$ is a closed set containing $iA\setminus kB,$ we have $k(iA\setminus kB)\subset c(iA\cap kB),$ hence $(iA\cap kB)\cap k(iA\setminus kB)=\varnothing.$ Thus, since we also have $iA\cap V=\varnothing,$ the equation above implies the first equation in the claim. Applying $i$ to both sides of the inclusion $k(iA\setminus kB)\subset A$ yields $ik(iA\setminus kB)\subset iA.$ The second equation follows.

**Corollary 2.** $ki(A\cap cB)\setminus iki(A\cap cB)=V.$

*Proof.* Note that $i(A\cap cB)=iA\cap icB=iA\setminus kB.$ By Claim 3, we conclude that $$\eqalign{ki(A\cap cB)\setminus iki(A\cap cB)&=&k(iA\setminus kB)\setminus ik(iA\setminus kB)\cr&=&[(iA\setminus kB)\cup V]\setminus ik(iA\setminus kB)\cr&=&[(iA\setminus kB)\setminus ik(iA\setminus kB)]\cup [V\setminus ik(iA\setminus kB)]\cr&=&[i(iA\setminus kB)\setminus ik(iA\setminus kB)]\cup V\cr&=&\varnothing\cup V\cr&=&V.}$$

Since $kiA\setminus ikiA=A\setminus iA=V,$ this proves that $$kiA\setminus ikiA=ki(A\cap cB)\setminus iki(A\cap cB).$$

This answers the question, but for completeness, we also show that the diagrams imply $A\cup cB$ is clopen.

**Claim 4.** $iB\setminus iA$ is clopen.

*Proof.* Since $iB$ and $i(A\cap B)$ are both clopen, it follows that $iB\setminus iA=iB\setminus (iA\cap iB)=iB\setminus i(A\cap B)$ is also clopen.

**Claim 5.** $iB\cap V=\varnothing.$

*Proof.* Since $iB\cap V\subset iB\setminus iA,$ if $iB\cap V\neq\varnothing,$ then Claim 4 implies $iB\setminus iA$ is a nonempty open set such that $(iB\setminus iA)\cap A\subset V,$ contradicting $i_AV=\varnothing.$ Thus $iB\cap V=\varnothing.$

**Claim 6.** $A\cup cB$ is clopen.

*Proof.* Claim 5 implies $iB\setminus iA=iB\setminus A.$ But  $iB\setminus A=(B\setminus Y)\setminus A=B\setminus A$ since $Y\subset A.$ Thus $B\setminus A$ is clopen by Claim 4. Hence $c(B\setminus A)=A\cup cB$ is also clopen. $\blacksquare$